# Grid data setup control

Tags: c#, gridview, datagrid

I am struggling with the grid view control and it seems I miss something as I am
not able to show data in it. I am trying the bind the control to a list of some
objects.
Can you please walk me through and explain how I need to setup the control?

Comment: My sample class is below:
public class GridDataModel
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
public bool Checked { get; set; }
}

Comment: You can just edit your question instead of posting as comment.

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you getting any errors?  Do you have code you can show that is more than your model....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a lot here since I don't have any code to go off of....

Given a `List<GridDataModel>` you would set your `DataSource` property to it and call `DataBind` method of your GridView.

```
var myData = GetMyData(); //this function builds the List<GridDataModel>

MyGrid.DataSource = myData;
MyGrid.DataBind();
```

[A more complete example.](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-bind-GridView-with-Generic-List-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)